# Odesk API Billing Reports

Tags: php, api, odesk

I've been trying to Generate Billing Reports for a Specific Provider on Odesk API using PHP. I tried using the URL below with authentication:

```
https://www.odesk.com/gds/finreports/v2/providers/12345/billings?tq=SELECT amount
 WHERE date >= '2009-10-01' AND date <= '2009-10-31'&tqx=out:json
```

This always gives me a `401 Unauthorized` error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if there are additional steps that I need to perform. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: So do you authenticate in some way? If not - do you believe API would share a financial information of any member to anyone?

Comment: Yes I'm using Authentication using Token. We will only use my account to get my financial data to generate billing reports.

Comment: Here is the link on generating this kind of report.http://developers.odesk.com/w/page/25401066/Financial%20Reports%20GDS%20API

Answer (score 0):

Danny,
i don't believe that people can guess
- what type of auth you use
- how you generate and sign your request
- how you request data

The best way would be:
- login at oDesk in browser and open the query above in next tab to see it works as expected. If all is ok, it's definitely smth with signing of the request.
- read http://developers.odesk.com/Authentication-using-OAuth
- check http://developers.odesk.com/Examples, use one of them to compare requests with your ones 
- contact support team finally